# Can't get the value from the JSON (Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x7fff87b9c520) to 'NSDictionary' (0x7fff87b9d5b0))

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, macos

I'm just starting my way in programming, and I'm stuck with the problem of pulling parameters out of JSON.

Here is what a JSON file looks like:

```
{
    "results": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "wind": {
                "degrees": 220,
                "speed_kts": 4,
                "speed_mph": 5,
                "speed_mps": 2
            },
            "temperature": {
                "celsius": 13,
                "fahrenheit": 55
            },
            "dewpoint": {
                "celsius": 12,
                "fahrenheit": 54
            },
            "humidity": {
                "percent": 94
            },
            "barometer": {
                "hg": 29.85,
                "hpa": 1011,
                "kpa": 101.09,
                "mb": 1010.92
            },
            "visibility": {
                "miles": "Greater than 6",
                "miles_float": 6.21,
                "meters": "10,000+",
                "meters_float": 10000
            },
            "elevation": {
                "feet": 98.43,
                "meters": 30
            },
            "location": {
                "coordinates": [
                    -6.06011,
                    36.744598
                ],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "icao": "LEJR",
            "observed": "2019-12-01T18:00:00.000Z",
            "raw_text": "LEJR 011800Z 22004KT 9999 FEW020 13/12 Q1011",
            "station": {
                "name": "Jerez"
            },
            "clouds": [
                {
                    "code": "FEW",
                    "text": "Few",
                    "base_feet_agl": 2000,
                    "base_meters_agl": 609.6
                }
            ],
            "flight_category": "VFR",
            "conditions": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to retrieve the barometric pressure in hPa (results => data => barometer => hpa).

And here is my code (I use Alamofire):

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request("https://api.checkwx.com/metar/lejr/decoded", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
          //  print(response)

            if let metardataJSON = response.result.value {

                let metarDataObject:Dictionary = metardataJSON as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                print(metarDataObject)

                let resultsObject:Dictionary = metarDataObject["results"] as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                let dataObject:Dictionary = resultsObject["data"] as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                let barometerObject:Dictionary = dataObject["barometer"] as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                let hpaObject:NSNumber = barometerObject["hpa"] as! NSNumber

                print(hpaObject)
            }
        }
```

After all the attempts, I cannot get rid of the error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT":

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x7fff87b9c520) to 'NSDictionary' (0x7fff87b9d5b0).
2019-12-01 19:34:18.723588+0100 Metar[6721:452116] Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x7fff87b9c520) to 'NSDictionary' (0x7fff87b9d5b0).
```

Can anyone shed some light on this issue and help me to improve my code?

Forgive me if the question seems simple or inappropriate - I'm just a beginner :)

Comment: Don’t do that. Use Decodable.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the first extraction line and refer to the `metarDataObject` in the second line. And note that inside `"data"` there is an array:

```
let dataObject:Dictionary = metarDataObject["data"] as! [[String: Any]]
let barometerObject:Dictionary = dataObject[0]["barometer"] as! [String: Any]
let hpaObject:NSNumber = barometerObject["hpa"] as! NSNumber
```

---

To not have to deal with these kinds of issues in the future I recommend to use some kind of "object mapping" framework which takes care of mapping the json into a useable, type-safe struct.